# ionic slide-box and google maps

Tags: google-maps, maps, height, ionic-framework, slide

I'm trying to get a google map (with javascript api) inside of an ion-slide-box with a dynamic height of 100%.
But the problem is the height is always 0px it works only if I set the height to a px value or if I remove the slide logic. For Example:

css:

```
#map {
height: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<ion-slide-box delegate-handle="bottomSlide" show-pager = "false">
        <ion-slide>
            <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
        </ion-slide></ion-slide-box>
```

Does anyone know why this happens or how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because parents of your div#map probably have a 0px height.

You need to figure out the guilty one.

Perhaps that CSS could do the trick:

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much that helped a lot!
now the map shows up but the map takes as height the whole screen and not just the container size... :/
do you have an advice for that too?

Comment: Does your container has `position: relative` CSS property? See this fiddle to understand the logic : http://jsfiddle.net/thibaudsowa/e1oL9w72/